# How to scrape multiple RSS feeds and store results respectively in their CSVs?

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, python-requests, rss

Is there a way one can scrape data from multiple RSS feeds and store results?

I'm scraping data from multiple RSS feeds and storing them respectively in their CSVs in the worst way possible - Separate .py files for each feed to their CSVs and running all .py files in the folder.

I have multiple py files like this in a folder with only the `url` different. I'm not sure how to run them in a loop and store the results in their respective CSVs

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = 'anyRSSFeedLink.com'
resp = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'html.parser')

output = []
for entry in soup.find_all('entry'):

    item = {
        'Title': entry.find('title', {'type': 'html'}).text,
        'Pubdate': entry.find('published').text,
        'Content': entry.find('content').text,
        'Link': entry.find('link')['href']
    }

    output.append(item)


df = pd.DataFrame(output)

df.to_csv('results/results_feed01.csv', index=False)
```

How can I read from a CSV that has all the RSS feed links like this:

[image: RSSFeedlinks]

And run them in a single scraping file while storing in their respective result's CSVs that looks something like this?

[image: RSSResults]

Comment: Show the relevant code (properly formatted in the question) and explain the specific issue to modify the code. If you can write CSVs you should be able to read them, too, and if you can process one RSS feed you should be able to handle a list of them in a loop.

Comment: To answer as general as your question is - Yes there is a way to implement this. However, so that the answers are not only based on opinions but can be specific, it would be great if you could improve your question again and share with us what you have tried so far. Thank you

Comment: Added my code, let me know if you need anything else too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way one can scrape data from multiple RSS feeds and store results?

Yes it is - Simply read your urls into a list or iterate directly over each line in your csv.

```
feeds = ['http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml','http://www.cbn.com/cbnnews/us/feed/']

for url in feeds:
    resp = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'xml')

    output = []
    for entry in soup.find_all('item'):

        item = {
            'Title': entry.find('title').text,
            'Pubdate': e.text if(e := entry.find('pubDate')) else None,
            'Content': entry.find('description').text,
            'Link': entry.find('link').text
        }

        output.append(item)
```

In each iteration you scrape the feed and save it to its csv, that e.g. could be named by domain, ...

```
 df.to_csv(f'results_feed_{url.split("/")[2]}.csv', index=False)
```

or use a counter if you like:

```
for enum, url in enumerate(feeds):
    ...
    df.to_csv(f'results_feed{enum}.csv', index=False)
```

**Be aware** - This will only work, if all feeds follows the same stucture, else you have to make some adjustments. You also should check if your elements you try to find are available before calling methods or properties:

```
'Pubdate': e.text if(e := entry.find('pubDate')) else None
```

##### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

feeds = ['http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml','http://www.cbn.com/cbnnews/us/feed/']

for url in feeds:
    resp = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'xml')

    output = []
    for entry in soup.find_all('item'):

        item = {
            'Title': entry.find('title').text,
            'Pubdate': e.text if(e := entry.find('pubDate')) else None,
            'Content': entry.find('description').text,
            'Link': entry.find('link').text
        }

        output.append(item)


    df = pd.DataFrame(output)

    df.to_csv(f'results_feed_{url.split("/")[2]}.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score -1):

output = [] has to be out of the loop, otherwise your result will be only the last url. If you check your cdv file, you will only have the feed of cbnnews. the result will be crushed.

code should be:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

feeds = ['http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml','http://www.cbn.com/cbnnews/us/feed/']

output = []

for url in feeds:
    resp = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'xml')

    for entry in soup.find_all('item'):

        item = {
            'Title': entry.find('title').text,
            'Pubdate': e.text if(e := entry.find('pubDate')) else None,
            'Content': entry.find('description').text,
            'Link': entry.find('link').text
        }

        output.append(item)


    df = pd.DataFrame(output)

    df.to_csv(f'results_feed_{url.split("/")[2]}.csv', index=False)
```

now if you check your cdv file, you will have both url feeds.

Comment: I am unsure how this helps? The output array already looks like it's outside the loop in the question 

Comment: my answer was for HedgeHog code